# Cambiar La lista de DropDownList en el evento OnChange

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

buen día

tengo el siguiente código para asignado a un listado a mi DropDownList desde el controller

```
ViewBag.Ciudad = new SelectList(GetCiudadAll, "idCiudad", "NombreCiudad");
```

en la vista

```
   @Html.DropDownList("Ciudad", (SelectList)ViewBag.Ciudad, "-- Seleccione Ciudad --", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
```

pero se necesita que para ciertos tipos de Impuesto se cambie el listado de ciudades para esto realizo esto en la vista

```
    <script type=“text/javascript”>
    $('#TipoImpuesto').change(function() {
               if ($('#TipoImpuesto').val() == ('CO2')) {
                    {
                      var CiudadesPaises = ['Mexico', 'Caracas', 'Bogota', 'Lima', 'Quito'];
                        @ViewBag.Ciudad=CiudadesPaises;
                    }
                }
            });
</script>
```

pero el DropDownList no cambia el listado que tiene que visualizar, como o porque no se puede visualizar el nuevo listado en mi vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el codigo que muestras estas mezclando partes que ejecutan en el cliente y partes en el servidor, esno no funciona

Si quieres cambiar dinamicamente usando codigo cliente los items del combo debes usar jquery, pero el ViewBag no tiene nada que ver, eso solo aplica cuando envias datos desde el action a la view cuando se renderiza en el servidor

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
    $('#TipoImpuesto').change(function() {
       if ($('#TipoImpuesto').val() == ('CO2')) {
            {
                $('#Ciudad').find('option').remove();

                var CiudadesPaises = ['Mexico', 'Caracas', 'Bogota', 'Lima', 'Quito'];

                $.each(CiudadesPaises, function( index, value ){
                    var option = $('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    $('#Ciudad').append(option);
                });

            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

como veras la idea es seleccionar el combo y usar el `append()` para agregar options, pero todo se hace por medio de codigo javascript/jquery

Comment: hola Leandro, y si se cambia nuevamente como recupero las ciudades iniciales?

Comment: podrias realizar una llamada ajax al action (usando $.ajax de jquery) que retorne un json con las ciudades, entonces iteras el json y usas el mismo codigo que define los options del combo

Comment: @LeandroTutini    sabiendo que tengo ViewBag.Ciudades como asigno esto a Un Json??

Comment: es que el viewbag no se asigna a ningun json, se supone que las ciudades debes devolverlas como respuesta de un action y es por medio del $.ajax de jquery que lo invocaras y obtendras ese json de respuesta